# Using multiple databases in a single webapi Controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a dotnet core (2.1) webapi project with EntityFramework (2.1)

What I have is a `IProjectRepository` interface:

```
public interface IProjectRepository
{
    void GetProject(Guid id);
    void DeleteProject(Guid id);
    Project CreateProject(Project prj);
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

I also implement it in the `ProjectRepository` class:

```
public class ProjectRepository : IProjectRepository
{
    private readonly ProjectContext context;

    public ProjectRepository(ProjectContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Project GetProject(Guid id)
    {
        return context.Projects.Find( id );
    }

    public void DeleteProject(Guid id)
    {
        context.Projects.Remove( project );
    }

    public void CreateProject(Project prj)
    {
        context.Projects.Add(project);
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Further I have a `ProjectsController`:

```
[Route( "api/[controller]" )]
[ApiController]
public class ProjectsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IProjectRepository projectRepository;

    public ProjectsController(IProjectRepository projectRepository)
    {
        this.projectRepository = projectRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet( "{id}", Name = "GetProject" )]
    public ActionResult<Project> GetProjectById( Guid id )
    {
        Project project = projectRepository.GetProject( id );

        if ( project == null )
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return project;
    }

    [HttpDelete( "{id}" )]
    public IActionResult DeleteProject( Guid id )
    {
        Project project = projectRepository.GetProject( id );

        if ( project == null )
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        projectRepository.RemoveProject( project );
        projectRepository.SaveChanges();
        return NoContent();
    }

    /* etc. */
}
```

I am configuring the repository in the `Startup.cs` - `ConfigureServices` function:

```
services.AddDbContext<ProjectContext>( opt => opt.UseSqlite( "Data Source=" + projectsPath + "\\Projects.db" ) );
services.AddScoped<IProjectRepository, ProjectRepository>();
```

What I want to achieve is to use different databases inside a single controller and also using an a single `Model`. So assuming I have two different `HttpPost`-Requests in my `ProjectController`:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/foo")]
```

and

```
[HttpPost("{id}/bar")]
```

In case of `foo` I want to write to `foo.db` and in case of `bar` I want to write to `bar.db`. Simply adding multiple calls to `services.AddDbContext<ProjectContext>` obviously will not work.
What is a good approach in order to achive my goal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Simply adding multiple calls to services.AddDbContext obviously will not work.

That approach would work if you used inheritance and called `AddDbContext` with the child classes.

Define two more  contexts that inherit from `ProjectContext`.

```
public class FooContext : ProjectContext {}

public class BarContext : ProjectContext {}
```

Then register them both with different connection strings.

```
services.AddDbContext<FooContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlite("..."))

services.AddDbContext<BarContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlite("..."))
```

Comment: Ok this is a helpful hint, maybe you could elaborate a little more on how to treat this kind of change in the `ProjectsController` and above all in the `ProjectRepository` class.

Comment: and the migrations? How to get the migrations of the different contexts with this response?